# HTML Canvas performance difference between Linux and Windows

Tags: linux, windows, performance, canvas

We made some measurements of HTML 5 Canvas drawing performance using http://www.kevs3d.co.uk/dev/canvasmark/ and we noticed that we got a much higher performance out of Linux than Windows:

```
╔═════════════════════╦═══════╦═════════╦════════════╗
║      CPU short      ║ Score ║   OS    ║  Browser   ║
╠═════════════════════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════════╣
║ Intel i7-4790       ║ 13309 ║ Linux   ║ Firefox 70 ║
║ Intel i7-4790       ║ 13323 ║ Linux   ║ Chrome 77  ║
║ Intel i5-8400       ║ 13172 ║ Linux   ║ Firefox 70 ║
║ Intel i5-8400       ║ 11873 ║ Linux   ║ Chrome 77  ║
║ Intel Pentium G2030 ║  4863 ║ Windows ║ Firefox 69 ║
║ Intel Pentium G2030 ║  5380 ║ Windows ║ IE 11      ║
║ Intel Core i7-4770S ║  6146 ║ Windows ║ Firefox 69 ║
║ Intel Core i3-6100  ║  8387 ║ Windows ║ Firefox 69 ║
║ Ryzen 7 1700        ║  9100 ║ Windows ║ Firefox 70 ║
║ Ryzen 7 1700        ║ 12897 ║ Linux   ║ Firefox 70 ║
║ Ryzen 7 1700        ║ 10870 ║ Linux   ║ Chrome     ║
╚═════════════════════╩═══════╩═════════╩════════════╝
```

### Questions

- What is the reason for this discrepancy?
- Is there some way to get the same performance under Windows than Linux?
- The Ryzen 7 has an Nvidia 1070Ti GPU while the other only have internal GPUs but it is slower than even the 5 year old i7-4790. Is there some way to enable GPU acceleration for Canvas and why is the Ryzen so slow?

Comment: Why not equalize the test and run the Windows machine with a Linux LiveCD/DVD

Comment: @ivanivan: That is a great idea! There is one machine that is measured with both (the Ryzen 7 1700).  Unfortunately we do not have permission to use other operating systems on the other machines.

Comment: IMHO this doesn't tell much. Why is theLinux+Intel perf equivalent between FF and Chrome, for the Core I7 but not for the Core I5 and Ryzen? On my own machine I have important variations between two runs of the same test (8900-9500). I even had a case where I reached 21708  possibly because the page was masked by something else. Also I don't see my PC getting more than 25% busy, which means it uses two cores max, so there can be a difference between the many-slow-cores and a-few-fast-cores CPU types.

Comment: @xenoid: Can you suggest a better benchmark for this purpose that better reflects real-world performance?

Comment: Only 2 lines of your benchmark are comparable: the Ryzen 7 1700 Windows and Ryzen 7 1700  Linux. All the rest are not fair tests. You also don't list graphics cards.

Comment: No idea for a better benchmark... To make it worse I tried again at home (same computer).  Instead of 9000-9500 the score is around 12500. The only difference is that my home network is much faster. So a difference could be how the network works between Linux and Windows, or how the browser caches things.